# what is the reason Validation not working Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to validate `firstName`, but it doesn't work. Even if I set not empty first name I keep getting message error it throw only error message

//BO

```
    import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
    @NotEmpty(message = "should not be empty")
    private String firstName;
```

//controller

```
    import jakarta.validation.Valid;
    @PostMapping("/e")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sayHello(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee) {
        String message = "Hello!";
        return ResponseEntity.ok(message);
    }
```

//Handling validation execption

```
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> handleValidationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().forEach(error ->
                errors.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage()));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(errors);
    }
```

Pom.Xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>

    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Are those the only dependencies you have? No conflicting ones? Which `@NotEmtpy` annotation are you using, which SPring Boot version are you using? What is it you see and what do you expect to see (that isn't clear).

Comment: @M.Deinum i m using spring boot without version

Comment: @M.Deinum import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

Comment: No you aren't using Spring Boot without a version it is either in your dependency management section or as a parent. There has to be a version else Maven wouldn't work. You still haven't described what you expect to see vs. what you actually do see.

Comment: @M.Deinum  <version>3.1.1</version>

Comment: @M.Deinum i want to show message error when its empty and response message = Hello when its not  i got both cases error empty and not empty it give me in all time an error message of NotEmpty

Comment: Perhaps forgot the `@Validated` annotation on top of the controller?

Comment: @JAsgarov it still not work

Comment: `@Validated` on the top-level serves a totally different purpose and is handled differently, in-fact it can make things worse. I still don't fully get what you have that isn't working as your question is unclear/too short in that regard. Apparently you always get the message. Hence you aren't sending the same field/parameter as it will map to . Show the request you are sending.